# How to install @types for all node modules automatically

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I am new to Typescript and NodeJs. Whenever I mention a node module in `package.json` and while importing the the node module, I always get the following errors.

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'ini'. 'e:/typescript-2020-1/parser1/node_modules/ini/ini.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/ini` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'ini';`
    
Could not find a declaration file for module 'json-query'. 'e:/typescript-2020-1/parser1/node_modules/json-query/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/json-query` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'json-query';`
```

To solve this problem, I always search and install the followings in `package.json` as given below.

```
"dependencies": {
    "ini": "^1.3.5",
    "@types/ini": "^1.3.30",
    "json-query": "^2.2.2",
    "@types/json-query": "^2.2.0"
    "@types/node": "^13.9.0"
}
```

How to avoid inclusion of all types of node modules specific types?
Is it possible to do in a way that `@types/<node module>` will be added automatically inside node_modues without directly adding to `package.json`?

I tried to add the following in `tsconfig.json` also, but it is not working.

```
"typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
],
```

Again my question is "Is it always necessary to add `@types` for each and every node modules?"

Comment: afaik, if the module has no type declaration (included directly or as a dependency), then the corresponding `@types` module must be added, as you do, as a dependency in `package.json`.
By default, all modules under `@types` (once installed) are visible, `types` and `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json` are used to change this default visibility. Doc: [tsconfig.json - @types, typeRoots and types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)

Comment: @Tobías, few modues do not have typings, some modules have. As a developer, I understand which node module to install, but how to achieve that in case of typescript, the typings will be added for that specific node module.

Comment: If a module declares a `types` element in `package.json` it has types declaration. If not I try to install them from @types repo like `npm install @types/module-name`. But some modules simply have no type definition. Neither the author nor anyone else has created them. In that case, if I want or must use it I make a types definition (`.d.ts` file) for the module by myself. I don't know if there is any way to get the types automatically generated.

Answer (score 8):

If an npm package contains types, you will get them for free when you install.

If not, then you may be able to find them under the @types namespace on npm.

There is a useful tool called [typac](https://github.com/ewgenius/typac) that you can install or run via `npx` that will try to install the @types for your package when you use it to install any npm package.

i.e.

```sh
    npx typac ini -i
```

Comment: This `ini` command and the `-i` flag are invalid on the latest version. I could not find a replacement so this solution no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

`typesync`

> "Installs missing TypeScript typings for dependencies in your
> package.json."
>
> https://github.com/jeffijoe/typesync

<sub>(typac development seems to have stalled.)</sub>